# Joomla - Cannot configure RSSocial! module

Tags: joomla

I am currently trying to use RSSocial! extension to add social media button that can link to my social media site. However, when I follow the instruction to edit the module, there is no parameter that I can change and this is what it showed:

[image: joomla]

Pressing "Show full description..." show nothing.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Many thanks.

P/s: If there is other way to do the same, I would really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Uninstall and then re-install the extension
- Disable PowerAdmin (I suspect that this is the problem)

Let us know of your findings.